# Highcharts with ajax/ json and SQL Server ASP.NET

Tags: json, sql-server, ajax, highcharts

I am new to Highcharts and Json data. I am trying to draw pretty simple column chart but failing to do so. below is my code.

HTML:

```
<div id="container"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'HighCharts.aspx/GetServices',
                type: 'POST',
                async: true,
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                data: '{}',
                success: function (response) {
                    DrawServices(response.d);
                },
                error: function () {
                    window.open("ErrorPage.aspx", "_self")
                }
            });
        });

        function DrawServices(data) {
            debugger;
            if (data == null) {
                window.open("ErrorPage.aspx","_self")
            }
            else {               
                $('#container').highcharts({
                    chart: {
                        type: 'column'
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: 'Services Data'
                    },
                    xAxis: {
                        categories: data[0].Name
                    },
                    yAxis: {
                        title: {
                            text: 'Total Servcies Requested'
                        }
                    },
                    series: data[0].Total
                });
            }
        }
```

JSON response

```
[{"Name":"Access the company internet","Total":489},{"Name":"Application Enhancement","Total":97},{"Name":"Catering Service","Total":250},{"Name":"Desktop","Total":350},{"Name":"Development and Consultation","Total":566},{"Name":"Email","Total":175},{"Name":"Laptop","Total":200},{"Name":"Maintenance","Total":32},{"Name":"Push Email","Total":700},{"Name":"Vehicle Sticker","Total":1200}]
```

Please guide me what i am doing wrong. blank chart is displaying

Answer (score 0):

You can set x-axis type to `category` and map your data to the format required by Highcharts, for example: `[point.name, point.y]`

```
    xAxis: {
        type: 'category'
    },
    series: [{
        data: data.map(el => [el.Name, el.Total])
    }]
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/r709soxe/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.type

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.data

Comment: Thanks for  your response. I am getting syntax error under > sign...

Comment: Hi @Shahid, Please check your code, as you can see in the provided example everything works as it should.

Comment: can you please guide me what going on in series code you provided. so i can better understand and debug it... because now i am getting error "el is not defined"

Comment: you didn't used function but just plain JavaScript. I want to use it by ajax function.

Comment: I used an arrow function, it is almost the same as in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/p93cwsgk/ You should be able to use the same approach in your ajax function.

Comment: Thanks again for you reply. when i am using plain JS then its working fine. but after getting data from ajax and using "map" inside function its giving error on map.

Comment: That is strange, please test this function: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/su69oenp/

Comment: JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'push' of undefined or null reference

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, it should be `processedData[0].data.push`. Please check this working example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/pvd8mkx4/

Comment: x axis labels are not showing as name instead its showing a,b,c,d,s,e.

Comment: `xAxis.type` should be set to `category`: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/gy0berjL/